# using array push in jquery by accessing php array variable

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

this is my php code:

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")&&(isset($_POST["btn_save"]))) {
    $schoolsInput=$_POST['schoolsInput'];

     echo $schoolsInput[0];
}
```

this is my jquery code:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
var counter=1;
var max_fields=5;
var add_button = $("#btn_addTxt");
var save_btn= $("#btn_save");
var wrapper= $("#prevSchoolTable");


  $(add_button).click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
if (counter == max_fields)  {
        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
    }
else {
    $(wrapper).append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="schoolsInput' + counter + '" id="schoolsInput' + counter + '" class="textbox" style="width:400px;">'
        + '</td></tr>');
    counter++;
    }
});
var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($schoolsInput); ?>;

$("#btn_save").click(function () {
        var msg = '';
        for(i=1; i<counter; i++){

            msg += "\n " + $('#schoolsInput' + i).val();
        }
        alert(msg); \\array push must go here
    });

});
</script>
```

I've search how can i access PHP variable and they say to use:

```
var obj = <?php echo json_encode($schoolsInput); ?>;
```

But everytime i put this on my jquery, the ADD function is not working.

any suggestion?

Comment: You need to JSON encode it on the client side with JS, using JSON.stringify (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), and then JSON decode it (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the PHP side of things. Plus, you also need to post that `arrayFormPHP` and I don't see that in any part of your JS code.

Comment: Use the php variable with in quotes
var arrayFromPHP = "<?php echo json_encode($schoolsInput); ?>";